# Cython cython.parallel unrecognized import

Tags: parallel-processing, cython

I am trying to use parallelism in cython. I am not able to import the cython module 'parallel'.

I have tried the following variations to no avail:

```
from cython import parallel
import cython.parallel
cimport cython.parallel
from cython.parallel cimport prange
from cython.parallel import prange
```

At the top of a .pyx file. Nothing else is included in the file so far. I get red underlines for the first line's "parallel" and the last and second last line's "prange" with unresolved references. I am using cython version 0.27.

When typing the import statement

```
import cython.pa___________
```

once i type ".pa" the suggestions are "cython.set_initial_path, cython.test_assert_path_exists, cython.test_fail_if_path_exists, cython.wraparound". I am using Intellij PyCharm professional edition.

Other parallel code has the following usually at the top of their code:

```
from cython.parallel import prange
```

which does not seem to work or exist for me. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct incantation is `from cython.parallel import prange`. Note that you are editing a cython file, not a python file. PyCharm is pointing out issues that would be a problem if this were a python file.

Comment: This is correct, and still shows underlines but is working. Note to other users: with nogil: must be used around prange block